# ios, get location every hour (ios7)

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

In my project I need to get location evry hour. My code looks like this:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate {
   UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
   CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

   locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
   locationManager.delegate = self;
   locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
   locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeOther;
   locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
   locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;

   return YES;
}                       

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
   __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task;

   background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^ {
    [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
    background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
   }];

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    while(TRUE)
    {
        NSLog(@"Background time Remaining: %f",[[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]);
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:200]; //wait for x sec

        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
    background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
   });


}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

   CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];

   NSDate* eventDate   = location.timestamp;
   NSTimeInterval time = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
   if (abs(time) < 15.0) {
    if (location != nil) {

        NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", location.coordinate.latitude];
        NSString *lng = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", location.coordinate.longitude];

        NSLog(@"location update  ...");

        //[APIConnection SaveMyPositionWitLat:lat withLng:lng];
        //[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
   }
}
```

This works, but battery im my phone is drained very fast and location is checking every second. If I enable:

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

then location service is stoped permanently. How to change this code for saving battery power ?

Comment: Now sleepForTimeInterval is 200 sec but I should be changed to 3600sec.

Comment: hi Please check this answer this will help you for sure as it helps me alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you set `locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` to `YES` this should help

Answer (score 1):

Your idea about getting the location is not really possible in iOS since your app needs a active location monitoring to keep running in the background.

For this Apple has the methods to check only major changes, [`startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW45).

This will inform you app of any major changes in location. Then what you could do to get a more accurate location is start the normal `startUpdatingLocation`.

This way you save battery and only grab the location when needed.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not possible to get location every hour with daving battery ? If yes I will back to my earlier solution based on startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges.

Comment: Doing scheduled task in iOS is near to impossible, you can ask the system if you could do a background task every hour. Then if the system allows it you will get about 10 sec every hour to do something. My solution will make sure that it will work and not it will not drain the battery that fast.